# jquery show/hide/toggle etc

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

JQUERY:

```
$("li h2").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("fast").siblings("div").slideUp("fast");
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>headingA</h2>
        <div>contentA</div>
        <h2>headingB</h2>
        <div>contentB</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

NOTES:
Bascially I'd want: when click on h2 show the div next to it and hide all others, not only show/hide toggle as well.
thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Your code seems to do exactly what you describe. http://jsfiddle.net/JSxMe/

Comment: I've already hide all the divs at the top (and more):
$("li div").hide();
$("li div:first").show();
$("li h2:first").addClass("active");

which works good:
( when click on a h2, shows the div next to it, click the h2 again then hide the div )

which doesn't work:
( click on another h2 it doesn't hide all the other divs )

Comment: It still seems to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/JSxMe/2/ When I click on any `h2`, whatever content is showing gets hidden. If the one I clicked on wasn't the active one, It becomes active, and its content gets shown. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JSxMe/2/ it works well, it is what i want. thanks!

Comment: @Ray - But I didn't change any of your code! :o) I just posted the code that you gave me, and gave a little color to the backgrounds. I'll post it as a solution, but really, it is just what you gave.

Comment: well, it looks like nothing changed, why mines won't work to me??

Comment: @Ray - So it works on jsFiddle, but not on your page?

Comment: @Ray - I updated my answer to wrap the code so that it runs after the DOM loads. Maybe that was the issue? jsFiddle wraps it automatically, so I left the code out there.

Comment: oddly. i won't be able to public the site right now. i guess the problem might be some html problems. because there are many pieces of table items inside each div, they are not w3c valided (with lots of ids etc errors). I have to ask the back-end guy to fix that. many thanks! patrick

Comment: this is the same i guess jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... });

Comment: @Ray - Yes, it is the same. Just shorter. I would have to see the actual HTML to know if it is correct. jQuery's traversal methods may change as the HTML structure changes.

Comment: i think i found the problem, the back-end guy added some inline styles on the divs display:block, which has the higher priority.

Comment: can you tell how it fix it easily in the my code? <div class="content" style="display: block;">

Comment: i gonna to run, will check the comments later, many thanks!

Comment: @Ray - `display:block` shouldn't have any negative impact on the code. A `div` has that property by default, and jQuery frequently adds that when it animates. Can you post your actual HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's *your* solution. Literally. I didn't make any change to your code, except to add a little CSS coloring.

**EDIT:** I modified it to run after the DOM loads.

CSS

```
.active {
    background: yellow;
}

div {
    background: orange;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>headingA</h2>
        <div>contentA</div>
        <h2>headingB</h2>
        <div>contentB</div>
        <h2>headingC</h2>
        <div>contentC</div>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

jQuery

```
   // Remember to wrap your code to run after the DOM is loaded.
$(function() {
    $("li div").hide();
    $("li div:first").show(); 
    $("li h2:first").addClass("active");

    $("li h2").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("fast").siblings("div").slideUp("fast");
    });​
});
```